# Hibernate expecting Date for Timestamp database column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, date, spring-data-jpa

I am using projections to retrieve a subset of columns into a DTO. Below is the DTO

QuestionPreviewDto.java

```
private Long id;
private String question;
private Timestamp datePosted;

public QuestionPreviewDto(Long id, String question, Timestamp datePosted){
    this.id = id;
    this.question = question;
    this.datePosted = datePosted;
}
```

Database table

```
CREATE TABLE question
(
    id               BIGINT NOT NULL,
    question         varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    date_posted      TIMESTAMP,
    .....
 )
```

Below is the repository method to populate the DTO where `QuestionEntity` is the entity class mapped to the database table `question`.

```
@Query("select new QuestionPreviewDto(id, question, datePosted) from QuestionEntity where id = :id")
QuestionPreviewDto getQuestionPreview(@Param("id") Long id);
```

The query above give me the following error

> Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [QuestionPreviewDto]. Expected arguments are: long, java.lang.String, java.util.Date
>   [cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: QuestionPreviewDto]

Not sure why Hibernate is expecting `java.util.Date` when type for `datePosted` is `Timestamp` in database and Java class ?

Comment: FYI, both `Date` & `Timestamp` classes in Java are now obsolete, supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Hibernate and [JPA 2.2](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/) both support *java.time*. For a database column of type akin to the SQL standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` you should be using `java.time.OffsetDateTime` instead of `Timestamp`.

Comment: Why don't you use `Date` or `LocalDateTime` instead of `TimeStamp`?

Comment: @ShekharRai But it still expects util.Date.

Comment: Are you SURE you made changes on `private java.util.Date datePosted;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the DTO you can use Date only with Temporal as Timestamp like below

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date utilTimestamp;
```

While you save it in Date in DTO it will automatically converted in to timestamp its a timestamp in DB.

Comment: Well, this works using `util.Date` but doesn't seem to be the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `QuestionEntity`
mapped properly according to O\R mapping documentation:

> date, time, timestamp
>   Type mappings from java.util.Date and its subclasses to SQL types DATE, TIME and TIMESTAMP (or equivalent).
>
> calendar, calendar_date
>   Type mappings from java.util.Calendar to SQL types TIMESTAMP and DATE (or equivalent).

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-entitiesvalues

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my quarkus application using hibernate.
I solved it by changing the field in my **DTO** to Date and annotate it like this:

```
@Type(type="timestamp")
private Date datePosted;
```

This did not change the format of the timestamp, and my **Entity** class could still use the Timestamp type like this:

```
@Type(type="timestamp")
private Timestamp datePosted;
```

So apparently this workaround is only needed for DTO projection.